# Get child rows in an array based on Parent table in YII

Tags: yii

student table:

student_id     name
--------------     -----
1              aaaa
2              bbbb
3              cccc

subjects table:

subject_id   student_id  sub1    sub2  sub3
-----------  ----------  -----    ----  ----
1              1          30     40     60
2              1          40     13     88
3              1          50     76     45
4              1          40     65     87
5              2          30     34     78
6              2          40     54     76
7              2          70     45     67

One to Many relationship

I have the students list form. when I click on edit for student 1

I want to get all the child rows related to student1 in an array.

How do I do this. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the model of student table check the relations function..

```
public function relations() {        
    return array(
        'subjects' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Subject', 'student_id'),
 ......
    );
 }
```

where Subject is the name of the model of your subject table..

```
// List data need when populating dropdown from database values
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'subject_id', CHtml::listData($model->subjects,'subject_id','subject_name'));?>
```

Here $model is the model of the student in your student form view, the listdata function will list all the subjectsof the student and the dropDownList function will make dropdown of them...., if you are comfirtable in showing the subjects by id then replace subject_name with subject_id, otherwise What you need is a subject title in subject table..

I hope I solved your problem..fr more refrences read relations, dropdownlist and listdata in yii documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I will try this